# Adding custom code in head (header html tag)

Tags: backend, xml, custom

we want to add the google+ links / code to our head (html) tag in our website. We have a multisite. We could edit phtml, create phtm etc ...

What is the best way to do this? via xml update?

Or is there another way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**To answer your question:**
add this to `local.xml`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="cms/block" name="google_plus" as="google_plus">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>google_plus</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Now create a cms block with the identifier `google_plus` and put your content in it.

**To solve your problem (easier):**
Use the field `Miscellaneous Scripts` from `System->Configuration->Design->Head` and put your scripts in there. They will be added before the `</head>` tag and you can set different scripts per website or even store views.

Comment: You beat me to it by 5 seconds! But I second this. it's the best way!

Comment: @SanderMangel. Well It's about time. You beat me by a few seconds many times. :)

Comment: ahum. Thanks I ought to know that. Haven't been there in config since a long time ... but great answer many thanks. You helped us a bunch!